# Freezes (not crashes) with GCD, blocks and Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, freeze

I have recently rewritten my Core Data driven database controller to use Grand Central Dispatch to manage fetching and importing in the background. Controller can operate on 2 NSManagedContext's:

1. `NSManagedObjectContext *mainMoc` instance variable for main thread. this contexts is used only by quick access for UI by main thread or by `dipatch_get_main_queue()` global queue.
2. `NSManagedObjectContext *bgMoc` for background tasks (importing and fetching data for NSFetchedresultsController for tables). This background tasks are fired ONLY by user defined queue: `dispatch_queue_t bgQueue`  (instance variable in database controller object).

Fetching data for tables is done in background to not block user UI when bigger or more complicated predicates are performed.

Example fetching code for NSFetchedResultsController in my table view controllers:

```
-(void)fetchData{

dispatch_async([CDdb db].bgQueue, ^{

        NSError *error = nil;
        [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setPredicate:self.predicate];
        if (self.fetchedResultsController && ![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {

            NSSLog(@"Unresolved error in fetchData %@", error);
        }

        if (!initial_fetch_attampted)initial_fetch_attampted = YES;
        fetching = NO;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.table reloadData];
            [self.table scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20) animated:YES];
        });

    });
```

} // end of fetchData function

`bgMoc` merges with `mainMoc` on save using `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`:

```
- (void)bgMocDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {

    // CDdb - bgMoc didsave - merging changes with main mainMoc
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.mainMoc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
     // Extra notification for some other, potentially interested clients
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DATABASE_SAVED_WITH_CHANGES object:saveNotification];

    });
}

- (void)mainMocDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {

    // CDdb - main mainMoc didSave - merging changes with bgMoc
    dispatch_async(self.bgQueue, ^{
     [self.bgMoc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
     });
}
```

NSfetchedResultsController delegate has only one method implemented (for simplicity):

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self fetchData];

    });

}
```

This way I am trying to follow Apple recommendation for Core Data: 1 NSManagedObjectContext per thread. I know this pattern is not completely clean for at last 2 reasons:

1. `bgQueue` not necessarily fires the same thread after suspension but since it is serial, it should not matter much (there is never 2 threads trying access `bgMoc` NSManagedObjectContext dedicated to it).
2. Sometimes table view data source methods will ask NSFetchedResultsController for info from bgMoc (since fetch is done on bgQueue) like sections count, fetched objects in section count, etc....

Event with this flaws this approach works pretty well of the 95% of application running time until ...

**AND HERE GOES MY QUESTION:**

Sometimes, very randomly **application freezes but not crashes**. It does not response on any touch and the only way to get it back to live is to restart it completely (switching back to and from background does not help). 
No exception is thrown and nothing is printed to the console (I have Breakpoints set for all exception in Xcode).

I have tried to debug it using Instruments (time profiles especially) to see if there is something hard going on on main thread but nothing is showing up.

I am aware that GCD and Core Data are the main suspects here, but I have no idea how to track / debug this.

Let me point out, that this also happens when I dispatch all the tasks to the queues asynchronously only (using **dispatch_async** everywhere). This makes me think it is not just standard deadlock.

Is there any possibility or hints of how could I get more info what is going on? Some extra debug flags, Instruments magical tricks or build setting etc...

Any suggestions on what could be the cause are very much appreciated as well as (or) pointers to how to implement background fetching for NSFetchedResultsController and background importing in better way.

Comment: One subtle thing to be aware of - make sure that the background MOC is actually being created on a background queue. If it's created on the main thread/queue, there's special run loop integration that's triggered that can cause all sorts of weirdness, even if you only use it in the background queue.

Comment: Oh, also, if you can mandate iOS 5, this stuff is way easier. I'd be happy to write an answer to that effect but it's only worth discussing if you can drop 4.0.

Comment: Thank you for hint with creation thread. Unfortunately the customer is not ready to drop iOS 4 yet.

Comment: Can you describe how data is written to the foreground and background threads? It seems strange to be merging changes in both directions. For any given entity, we generally only save on the main thread's context, or read from the main thread's context and save on a background context that notifies the main thread's context.

Comment: Encountering the same problem. Any update on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first and very bad mistake was to fetch data for `NSFetchedResultsController` in the background queue.

It turned out after testing, I was way too sensitive about fetching times. I unnecessary did put `fetchData` execution to back thread making core data related code too complex when the longest fetch time I could generate took literally split of a second. This introduced way too much complexity and uncertainty for very small performance gain (if any).

I resigned form that by moving fetchData execution and all NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method to the main thread (simplified the code by removing GCD code).

When this was done I no longer needed `mainMocDidSave:` and unregistered from listening to the  `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` for main thread context.
I could also removed and unregistered DATABASE_SAVED_WITH_CHANGES notification posting.

This greatly simplified 'merging' mechanism as from this time on only background thread context  merges its changes with main thread context (when saved). Let's call it one directional change notifications.

`NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods will be fired automatically as they pickup main thread context changes after merge.

Another important thing is to change dispatch_async to **dispatch_sync** in:

```
- (void)bgMocDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {

    // CDdb - bgMoc didsave - merging changes with main mainMoc
        // Previously was: dispatch_async
        // dispatch_sync in this place may prevent from overlapping merging in some cases (many blocks in background queue)
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.mainMoc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
     // !!! Extra notification NO needed anymore

    });
}
```

**Rule of thumb:** SIMPLIFY and MINIMIZE amount of threads and NSManagedContexts.
I experienced that **having 2 contexts is enough even for very big apps**:

1. importContext  operating in dedicated to GCD queue (MUST be serial queue). Just remember to save it at the end of the queue block's code.
2. mainConstext to operate on main UI thread (I call it READ context ;-) to be use when pulling data for the UI (presentation).

Answer (score 1):

The DATABASE_SAVED_WITH_CHANGES notification looks a bit suspicious: Let's say bgMoc saves. Then `bgMocDidSave:` fires and merges the changes with the mainMoc which is fine. Then you fire a notification which in the end (I assume `mainMocDidSave:` fires when DATABASE_SAVED_WITH_CHANGES is raised) merges the changes back in bgMoc (which is where is originated from!). This does not sound like the right approach to me. 
Also you might want to check in `bgMocDidSave:` that the notification originates from the bgMoc. If the mainMoc saves then changes are that `bgMocDidSave:` also fires.

Comment: DATABASE_SAVED_WITH_CHANGES does not invoke neither mainMocDidSave: nor bgMocDidSave:. It is just extra/separate notification picked up by a UI elements  and controllers which does not use  NSFetchedResultsController so they can be aware of crucial changes.

Comment: If you've only registered NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification for the mainMoc and bgMoc then that should be fine. Do you really need the bgMoc? Threading with Core Data will complicate things considerably.

Comment: Yeah, I really need it. Sometimes when table view controllers performs fetches on main thread - it blocks UI for too long. The database can be quite big sometimes. And there are also a lots of import and synchronization with server data going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I've noticed that with big databases saving the Moc (which can be quite slow) will halt all the threads that use the same persistent store (and are fetching/faulting data).